How to Send Custom OTP Using Twilio in a Next.js 14 Signup/Login Flow?
I am working on a Next.js project and trying to implement a custom OTP verification process using Twilio. The OTP is generated, hashed, and stored securely in the database. However, I am facing an issue where the Twilio SMS API call intermittently fails with the error message: "Authenticate". Occasionally, the response shows a valid status, but the SMS is not delivered to the user's phone number.
Here’s what I have tried so far:

Generate OTP: I use a utility function (generateOtp) to generate the OTP and hash it using bcrypt before saving it to the database along with an expiration timestamp.
Send OTP via Twilio: I use Twilio's messages.create API to send the custom OTP to the user's phone number.
Verify OTP: On OTP verification, I retrieve the hashed OTP and expiry from the database, validate the expiry, and compare the entered OTP with the hashed OTP.

Code:
Here’s the function I’m using to send OTP via Twilio:
import twilio from "twilio";

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID!;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN!;
const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

export const sendOTP = async ({
  phoneNumber,
  otp,
  smsType,
}: {
  phoneNumber: string;
  otp: string;
  smsType: string;
}) => {
  try {
    const message = `Your ${smsType} is ${otp}. It is valid for 10 minutes.`;
    const response = await client.messages.create({
      body: message,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER!,
      to: phoneNumber,
    });

    console.log("Twilio Response:", response.sid);
    return {
      success: true,
      message: `Your ${smsType} has been sent successfully.`,
      response,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Error sending OTP:", error.message);
    return { success: false, error: error.message };
  }
};

Here’s the signup API route:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { sendOTP } from "@/utils/Sms"; // Use Twilio's SMS function
import User from "@/models/User";
import db from "@/utils/db";
import { generateOtp, getOtpExpiry } from "@/utils/OtpGenerate";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

db();

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const body = await request.json();
  const { phoneNumber } = body;

  if (!phoneNumber) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Phone number is required." },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }

  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ phoneNumber });
    if (existingUser) {
      if (existingUser.isVerified) {
        return NextResponse.json(
          { message: "User already exists and is verified." },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      } else {
        const otp = generateOtp();
        const hashedOtp = await bcrypt.hash(otp, 10);
        const otpExpiry = getOtpExpiry(10);

        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(existingUser._id, {
          otp: hashedOtp,
          otpExpiry,
        });

        await sendOTP({
          phoneNumber,
          otp,
          smsType: "SIGNUP OTP",
        });

        return NextResponse.json(
          {
            message:
              "User exists but is not verified. A new verification SMS has been sent.",
          },
          { status: 200 }
        );
      }
    }

    const otp = generateOtp();
    const hashedOtp = await bcrypt.hash(otp, 10);
    const otpExpiry = getOtpExpiry(10);

    const newUser = new User({
      phoneNumber,
      role: "user", 
      otp: hashedOtp,
      otpExpiry,
    });

    await newUser.save();

    await sendOTP({
      phoneNumber,
      otp,
      smsType: "SIGNUP OTP",
    });

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "OTP sent successfully to your phone!" },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error signing up user:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Error signing up user", error },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

Issue:
The OTP is generated, hashed, and stored correctly, but the Twilio SMS API fails intermittently with the "Authenticate" error. In some cases, the response shows a valid status, but the SMS is not actually delivered.
Expected Outcome:

The OTP should be sent successfully via SMS using Twilio.
The OTP should be securely stored and validated accurately during user verification.

Actual Result:

Sometimes, the response is successful, but the SMS is not delivered.
Other times, the "Authenticate" error is returned.

What I've Checked:

Ensured correct Twilio accountSid, authToken, and TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER values are set.
Double-checked the formatting of the phone number and other parameters.
Verified that Twilio credentials and API key permissions are correct.

What I Need Help With:

Troubleshooting why Twilio is intermittently failing with the "Authenticate" error.
Ensuring proper integration of Twilio for OTP SMS in Next.js.

I would appreciate any guidance on debugging or improving the integration! Thank you in advance!
